# Help me optimize this MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I have a MySql query that take a very long time to run (about 7 seconds). The problem seems to be with the OR in this part of the query: "(tblprivateitem.userid=?userid OR tblprivateitem.userid=1)". If I skip the "OR tblprivateitem.userid=1" part it takes only 0.01 seconds. As I need that part I need to find a way to optimize this query. Any ideas?

QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    tbladdeditem.addeditemid,
    tblprivateitem.iitemid,
    tblprivateitem.itemid
FROM tbladdeditem 
INNER JOIN tblprivateitem 
    ON tblprivateitem.itemid=tbladdeditem.itemid 
        AND (tblprivateitem.userid=?userid OR tblprivateitem.userid=1)
WHERE tbladdeditem.userid=?userid
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id    select_type    table            type    possible_keys    key    key_len    ref                    rows    extra
1     SIMPLE         tbladdeditem     ref     userid           userid 4          const                  293     Using where
1     SIMPLE         tblprivateitem   ref     userid,itemid    itemid 4          tbladdeditem.itemid    2       Using where
```

TABLES:

tbladdeditem contains 1 100 000 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbladdeditem` (
    `addeditemid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `itemid` int(11) default NULL,
    `userid` mediumint(9) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`addeditemid`),
    KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

tblprivateitem contains 2 700 000 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblprivateitem` (
    `privateitemid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `userid` mediumint(9) default '1',
    `itemid` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `iitemid` mediumint(9) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`privateitemid`),
    KEY `userid` (`userid`),
    KEY `itemid` (`itemid`) //Changed this index to only use itemid instead
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: So with the OR part it is impossible to get it to run like in 0.01 seconds?

Comment: The `OR`condition can be written as `tblprivateitem.userid IN (1, ?userid)` - but I doubt it will make any difference

Comment: Can you try adding a `(userid, itemid)` index in `tbladdeditem` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I made my queries and schema match your original question exactly, multi-column key and all.  The only possible difference is that I populated each table with two million entries.  My query (your query) runs in 0.15 seconds.

```
delimiter $$
set @userid = 6
$$
SELECT 
    tbladdeditem.addeditemid,    tblprivateitem.iitemid,    tblprivateitem.itemid
FROM tbladdeditem 
INNER JOIN tblprivateitem 
    ON tblprivateitem.itemid=tbladdeditem.itemid 
        AND (tblprivateitem.userid=@userid or tblprivateitem.userid = 1)
WHERE tbladdeditem.userid=@userid
```

I have the same explain that you do, and with my data, my query return over a thousand matches without any issue at all.  Being completely at a loss, as you really shouldn't be having these issues -- is it possible you are running a very limiting version of MySQL?  Are you running 64-bit?  Plenty of memory?

I had made the assumption that your query wasn't performing well, and when mine was, assumed I had fixed you problem.  So now I eat crow.  I'll post some of the avenues I went down.  But I'm telling you, your query the way you posted it originally works just fine.  I can only imagine your MySQL thrashing to the hard drive or something.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

**PREVIOUS RESPONSE (Which is also an update)**

I broke down and recreated your problem in my own database.  After trying independent indexes on `userid` and on `itemid` I was unable to get the query below a few seconds, so I set up very specific multi-column keys as directed by the query.  Notice on `tbladdeditem` the multi-column query begins with `itemid` while on the `tblprivateitem` the columns are reversed:

Here is the schema I used:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbladdeditem` (
  `addeditemid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`addeditemid`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `i_and_u` (`itemid`,`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblprivateitem` (
  `privateitemid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `itemid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `iitemid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`privateitemid`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `itemid` (`itemid`),
  KEY `u_and_i` (`userid`,`itemid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I filled each table with 2 million entries of random data.  I made some assumptions:

- userid varies from 1 to 2000
- itemid varies between 1 and 10000

This gives each user about a thousand entries in each table.

Here are two versions of the query (I'm using workbench for my editor):

Version 1 - do all the filtering on the join.

Result:  0.016 seconds to return 1297 rows

```
delimiter $$
set @userid = 3
$$
SELECT 
    a.addeditemid,
    p.iitemid,
    p.itemid
FROM tblprivateitem as p
INNER JOIN tbladdeditem as a
    ON (p.userid in (1, @userid))
        AND p.itemid = a.itemid 
        AND a.userid = @userid
$$
```

Here's the explain:

```
EXPLAIN: 
id select_type table type  key     ref  rows extra
1  SIMPLE      p     range u_and_i      2150 Using where; Using index
1  SIMPLE      a     ref   i_and_u      1    Using where; Using index
```

Version 2 - filter up front

Result: 0.015 seconds to return 1297 rows

```
delimiter $$
set @userid = 3
$$
SELECT 
    a.addeditemid,
    p.iitemid,
    p.itemid
from 
  (select userid, itemid, iitemid from tblprivateitem 
      where userid in (1, @userid)) as p
  join tbladdeditem as a on p.userid = a.userid and a.itemid = p.itemid;
where a.userid = @userid
$$
```

Here's the explain:

```
id select_type table      type  key     ref               rows extra
1  PRIMARY     <derived2> ALL   null    null              2152
1  PRIMARY     a          ref   i_and_u p.itemid,const    1    Using where; Using index
2  DERIVED     p1         range u_and_i                   2150 Using where
```

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation! I tried to change the index "itemid" to only use itemid as you suggested. (See my updated question on how my indexes looks now). No better performance, now even if I skip the OR part the query takes like 5-7 seconds to run. What am I missing?

Comment: Wow thanks for looking into this! We are running Linux, MySql 5.1, 4gb ram, this is outside my knowledge but our provider says it should be over what we need. Tonight I will try to set up multi-column keys just as you did and see if it is working faster. I have been looking at the status page in php-myadmin and it seems to be a lot of strange stuff going on (even if I'm not an expert), maybe we have some other problems with the server that is causing this slow performance.

Comment: Hey no problem.  My home computer is a bit of a monster.  I'm running MySQL 64 bit under windows 7 with 24 gigs of ram for comparison.

Comment: I have now been able to test with multi-column keys: "Version 1 - do all the filtering on the join" - runs in 16 seconds for me. A little difference in performance as yours run in 0.016sec.. I also tested my original solution on my PC running Windows 7, MySql 5.1. It runs in 0.001sec. Something must be really wrong with the Linux server. Any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: Holy smokies.  Not off hand, no, but (note to self: don't run on linux).  Kidding -- I've never personally maintained MySQL on Linux.  I found a thread that wasn't detailed, but pointed out specific version of MySQL on Linux that caused slowdown (5.0.18).  So, usual things, are you running auditing on MySQL in Linux?  Any way you can try upgrading to MySQL 5.6.  Anyway, I would have sworn it was memory thrashing -- if not system memory, then the memory allocated to MySQL.  Good luck, wish I knew more.  Please write to me if you find out what it is, I need closure!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would try this instead, on your original `JOIN` you have an `OR` associated with a parameter, move that to your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
    tbladdeditem.addeditemid,
    tblprivateitem.iitemid,
    tblprivateitem.itemid
FROM tbladdeditem 
INNER JOIN tblprivateitem 
    ON tblprivateitem.itemid=tbladdeditem.itemid 
WHERE tbladdeditem.userid=?userid
    AND (tblprivateitem.userid=?userid OR tblprivateitem.userid=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! That made a little difference in speed, got it down to running in like 6.5 seconds. Is it impossible to get it to run faster with the OR part?

Comment: @Martin I edited the answer with another version, using COALESCE

Comment: COALESCE will not give the same result will it? If I have ?userid=100 then it will get all from tblprivateitem where userid=100. Only if ?userid is null it will get all tblprivateitem where userid=1? What I need is: (tblprivateitem.userid=100 OR tblprivateitem.userid=1)

Comment: @Martin you are correct, i have multi-tasking and overlooked that. Do you have an index on the userid column?  I will remove the COALESCE version

Comment: Yes, there is and index for userid. I tried the UNION as Charles Bretana suggested and it run in 0.005 seconds. So maybe a UNION will work. But it would be nice to know why it isn't working like I do now. Can't MySql use the index when I use OR?

Comment: @Martin I am not sure why it is slowing down but if the UNION works, then go with that.

Comment: Union sidesteps the actual problem with the table schema, which is ultimately what is causing the slow performance.

Comment: @Michael I agree that UNION probably isn't the best method to fix the slowness. I just didn't have time to look further at the issue.

Comment: @bluefeet I didn't mean to sound confrontational if I did.  UNION is a perfectly good answer, and if the schema cannot be modified, then it's pretty much the only answer.

Comment: @Michael I know, no worries I didn't take it that way.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the predicate condition `tbladdeditem.userid=?userid`  in the where clause I don't think you need it in the join condition.. Try removing it from the join condition and (If you are using the Or to handle the case where the parameter is null, then use `Coalesce` instead of `OR`)  if not leave it as an Or

```
-- If Or is to provide default for when (?userid is null...
      SELECT  a.addeditemid, p.iitemid,  p.itemid 
      FROM tbladdeditem a 
        JOIN tblprivateitem p
          ON p.itemid=a.itemid 
      WHERE a.userid=?userid 
         AND p.userid=Coalesce(?userid, 1)
-- if not then
      SELECT  a.addeditemid, p.iitemid,  p.itemid 
      FROM tbladdeditem a 
        JOIN tblprivateitem p
          ON p.itemid=a.itemid 
      WHERE a.userid=?userid 
         AND (p.userid=?userid Or p.userid = 1)
```

Second, if there is not an index on the userId column in these two tables, consider adding one.

Finally, if these all fail, try converting to two separate queries and unioning them together:

```
      Select  a.addeditemid, p.iitemid,  p.itemid 
      From tbladdeditem a 
        Join tblprivateitem p
          On p.itemid=a.itemid 
            And p.userId = a.Userid
      Where p.userid=?userid 
      Union
      Select a.addeditemid, p.iitemid,  p.itemid 
      From tbladdeditem a 
        Join tblprivateitem p
          On p.itemid=a.itemid 
            And p.userId = a.Userid
      Where p.userid = 1
```